# BitLocker status “Not Encryptable” for my 2gb memory card

Tags: bitlocker

I am using 2gb memory card in my phone. I used BitLocker function in Windows 7. Now my memory card doesn't open and can't be formatted. When I open the card, the message

> Formatting memory

is displayed. Then the message

> Formatting memory incomplete

is shown. When the Memory card is connected, the status bar displays message status

> Not Encryptable

for my 2gb memory card